# Same subnet but invisible to eachother

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ip, subnet, nmap

I am trying to run an octopi server on the raspberry and connect to it with the laptop.

I managed to get two devices (a raspberry pi 4 and a laptop) to be on the same subnet of a public wifi network inside my building (namely 10.43.36.x).

Using nmap -sn I can look for all the devices around the building, and I get the same results, however, I don't see the other device.

The way I managed to get the devices on the same subnet was by copying the eth mac address of one device, randomizing the address with macchanger and then using the old mac on the new device to get a similar ip from the dhcp.

How can I solution this issue?

Comment: If you're on a public wifi network, it's likely that wireless client isolation is enabled, which would prevent two wifi devices from talking to each other even on the same subnet.

Comment: Weirdly, there are OTHER devices on the network that I can see and I can also see that they have port 22 open. Of course I don't know the user name and password, but I could connect to them if I did.

Comment: @satwell thank you for pointing this out. I managed to connect to the other device via VPN knowing I cannot connect directly because of client isolation. You could post this as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's common for public wifi networks to enable wireless client isolation, which would prevent two devices on the same wifi network from sending traffic to each other, even if they're on the same subnet.

If that's the case, then you'll need to either:

- Connect via some machine that both devices can reach.  There are lots of tools for this, including SSH tunnels, [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), VPNs, `stunnel`, and `socat`.
- Put them on a different wifi network that doesn't have client isolation.